# How can I disable link color change on ONE LINK?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a button where I want the text font color red, but it remains gray because it has been clicked before. How can I disable the link color change for this link?

**index.html.erb**

```html
<button class="button"><%= link_to 'New Value', new_value_path %></button>
```

**values.css.scss**

```html
.button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #4479BA;
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

**scaffolds.css.scss**

```html
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

p, ol, ul, td {
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

pre {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

div {
  &.field, &.actions {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

#notice {
  color: green;
}

.field_with_errors {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
}

#error_explanation {
  width: 450px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: -7px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #c00;
    color: #fff;
  }
  ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: square;
  }
}
```

Comment: try using `color: #FF0000!important;` or `.button:visited{color:#FF0000}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's **invalid** HTML - `anchor` can't be inside of a `button`.

Your best option is to style the `anchor` to look like a `button`:

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn">I'm a button</a>
```

Used the styles from [css3buttongenerator](http://css3buttongenerator.com/), and added the `.btn:active` to add some styles when the `anchor` is clicked and holded like that (notice the `color:red`).

Or to make the `button` to acts like the `anchor` - [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

**Update**

To use it with rails `link_to` helper, use it like:

```
<%= link_to "I'm a button", new_value_path, class: 'btn' %>
```

Comment: What do I put in parenthesis? <a href="" class="btn">I'm a button</a> I put "new_value_path" but that just gives me an error or <%= new_value_path %> but then the link stays gray.